# sencha touch 2 how create url dynamic store from item list

Tags: extjs, proxy, sencha-touch-2, store

I need to pass the value of selected item in the list to a list of detail to load data from a store.

The code view is

```
Ext.define('App.view.PresidentList', {
extend: 'Ext.List',
xtype: 'presidentlist',
requires: ['App.store.Presidents','Ext.dataview.NestedList','Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'],

config: {
    title: 'Events',
    iconCls: 'star',
    //grouped: true,
    itemTpl: '<b>{evento}</b><br>{nombre}',
    store: 'Presidents',
    onItemDisclosure: true,

}
```

});

The code controller is

```
Ext.define('App.controller.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
    refs: {
        main: 'mainpanel'
    },
    control: {
        'presidentlist': {
            disclose: 'showDetail'
        }
    }
},

showDetail: function(list, record) {

    var listItems = Ext.create('App.store.ListItems', {newUrl : record.getData()});
    listItems.load();

    this.getMain().push({
        xtype: 'presidentdetail',
        title: record.fullName(),
        data: record.getData(),
        store: listItems
    });
}
```

});

the code view datail is

```
Ext.define('App.view.PresidentDetail', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
xtype: 'presidentdetail',

config: {
    title: 'Details',
    scrollable: 'vertical',
    items:
    [
        {
            extend: 'Ext.List',
            xtype: 'presidentlist',
            requires: ['App.store.ListItems','Ext.dataview.NestedList','Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'],

            config: {
                title: 'Events',
                iconCls: 'star',
                //grouped: true,
                itemTpl: '<b>{evento}</b><br>{nombre}',
                store: 'ListItems',
                onItemDisclosure: true,

            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'nestedlist',
            title: 'Contactos',
            id: 'panel2',
            useToolbar:false, 
            displayField: 'title',
            store: {
                type: 'tree',
                fields: [
                    'title','link','author','contentSnippet','content',
                    {name: 'leaf', defaultValue: true}
                ],
                root: {
                    leaf: false
                },
                proxy: {
                    type: 'jsonp',
                    url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/SenchaBlog/',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        rootProperty: 'responseData.feed.entries'
                    }
                }
            },
            detailCard: {
                xtype: 'panel',
                scrollable: true,
                styleHtmlContent: true
            },
            listeners: {
                itemtap: function(nestedList, list, index, element, post) {
                    this.getDetailCard().setHtml(post.get('content'));
                }
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            id: 'panel5',
            title: 'Costos',
            iconCls: 'home'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Otros',
            iconCls: 'favorites',
            id: 'panel5'                
        },
    ]
}
```

});

and the code store of ListItems is

```
Ext.define('App.store.ListItems',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
autoLoad: true,
config: {
    model: 'App.model.President',
    proxy: {
        //autoLoad: true,
        type: 'ajax',
        url:<-------->here comes the url with the variable that is passed from the list
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: "test"
        }
    }
}
```

});

Please collaboration with this issue not to do this. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the url of the proxy on a store, you can do like this

```
Ext.getStore('YourStoreId').getProxy().setUrl("your_new_url");
Ext.getStore('YourStoreId').load();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use estraParams inside the proxy
extraParams:{Parm1:2, Parm2:'eeee'},